# Android write on external Storage

Tags: android, extern

I'm trying to write some drawables in my extornal storage with this code :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.paco);

        File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "paco.png");
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
            Log.d("XXXXX","voy a cerrar");
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("XXXXX","eeeee", e);
        }
```

But I keep getting this error:

> 28476-28476/com.example.usuari.myapplication3 E/XXXXX: eeeee
>                                                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/paco.png: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>                                                                                 at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87)
>                                                                                 at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.MainActivity.iniciarDrawables(MainActivity.java:276)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)
>                                                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>                                                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>                                                                                 at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
>                                                                                 at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.MainActivity.iniciarDrawables(MainActivity.java:276) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

I have the permission entry in my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usuari.myapplication3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

...
```

Edit: I'm working with sdk 23

Comment: If your target SDK is 23 or higher, you need to request the permissions at run time: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: what sdk version you are testing..?

Comment: If you're using API 23 or higher, you have to request permissions for user. [See this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Edited, currently working with sdk 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Sdk >=23 needs runtime permission from user. Only adding permission to manifest will not work.

Try this code:

```
 if(isPermissionGranted()){
      //open file
    }
 public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

catch the permission result in:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //call your method open file
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on API 23+, you have to request the permissions at RunTime (although they are already present in the manifest file).

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, check that your storage is ready:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState(file) != Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
    // your storage is not ready for work, do something with this
}
```

Secondly, as far, as I remember, starting from Kit-Kat you can not write to the root of external storage.
It is only allowed to write to application specific folder on the storage.
To get this folder, use

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(directoryType);
```

What about directoryType, check method`s documentation, you, probably, want to use Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES.

Try this.